# how to correctly use google map charts in an aspx page

Tags: html, asp.net, google-maps, google-visualization

I have taken an example from **Google Charts Maps** page https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/ and it is working fine when I paste it in a new file and save it as **html** page. But when I use the same thing in an **aspx** page the map fails to load and it says **This page didn't load Google Maps correctly**. Here is my .aspx page -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ShowOffices.aspx.cs" Inherits="OfficeLocationMarker.ShowOffices" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['map']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap () {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Address');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Location');

      data.addRows([
        ['Lake Buena Vista, FL 32830, United States',                  'Walt Disney World'],
        ['6000 Universal Boulevard, Orlando, FL 32819, United States', 'Universal Studios'],
        ['7007 Sea World Drive, Orlando, FL 32821, United States',     'Seaworld Orlando' ]
      ]);

      var options = {
        mapType: 'styledMap',
        zoomLevel: 12,
        showTip: true,
        useMapTypeControl: true,
        maps: {
          // Your custom mapTypeId holding custom map styles.
          styledMap: {
            name: 'Styled Map', // This name will be displayed in the map type control.
            styles: [
              {featureType: 'poi.attraction',
               stylers: [{color: '#fce8b2'}]
              },
              {featureType: 'road.highway',
               stylers: [{hue: '#0277bd'}, {saturation: -50}]
              },
              {featureType: 'road.highway',
               elementType: 'labels.icon',
               stylers: [{hue: '#000'}, {saturation: 100}, {lightness: 50}]
              },
              {featureType: 'landscape',
               stylers: [{hue: '#259b24'}, {saturation: 10}, {lightness: -22}]
              }
        ]}}
      };

      var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

      map.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GvOffcDet" OnRowDataBound="GvOffcDet_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="OfficeID">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/plus.png" Height="20px" Width="20px"  />
                        <asp:Panel runat="server">
                            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GvEmpDetails"></asp:GridView>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>

   <div id="map_div" style="height: 500px; width: 900px"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have copy pasted the example and saved it as a html file. In this case it is working and the map is shown .Here is the code -

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['map']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap () {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Address');
      data.addColumn('string', 'Location');

      data.addRows([
        ['Lake Buena Vista, FL 32830, United States',                  'Walt Disney World'],
        ['6000 Universal Boulevard, Orlando, FL 32819, United States', 'Universal Studios'],
        ['7007 Sea World Drive, Orlando, FL 32821, United States',     'Seaworld Orlando' ]
      ]);

      var options = {
        mapType: 'styledMap',
        zoomLevel: 12,
        showTip: true,
        useMapTypeControl: true,
        maps: {
          // Your custom mapTypeId holding custom map styles.
          styledMap: {
            name: 'Styled Map', // This name will be displayed in the map type control.
            styles: [
              {featureType: 'poi.attraction',
               stylers: [{color: '#fce8b2'}]
              },
              {featureType: 'road.highway',
               stylers: [{hue: '#0277bd'}, {saturation: -50}]
              },
              {featureType: 'road.highway',
               elementType: 'labels.icon',
               stylers: [{hue: '#000'}, {saturation: 100}, {lightness: 50}]
              },
              {featureType: 'landscape',
               stylers: [{hue: '#259b24'}, {saturation: 10}, {lightness: -22}]
              }
        ]}}
      };

      var map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'));

      map.draw(data, options);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_div" style="height: 500px; width: 900px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I correctly load the map in the .aspx page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Excerpt from their blog](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.in/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html) -

> As of June 22, 2016 we are making the following changes to the Google
> Maps APIs Standard Plan:
>
> We no longer support **keyless access** (any
> request that doesn't include an API key). Future product updates are
> only available for requests made with an API key. API keys allow us to
> contact developers when required and help us identify misbehaving
> implementations.

The google map charts uses Google Map APIs.
Recently they made changes in their APIs

So usage of the Google Maps APIs now requires a key.
If you are using Google Maps API on localhost after 22nd June 2016, you will need a key to use it

You can get a key from their page - [Get API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key)